# Linux run shell cmd from python, Failed to load config file

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I have installed a backup program called rclone on my raspberry pi which is running Debian, I have successfully ran the cmd in the shell to backup a folder to google drive but I really need to be able to do so each time a take a photo with my python script, I have little experience in Linux compared to others and I thought that if I made a shell script with a basic shebang of

```
 #!/bin/sh
```

or

```
 #!/bin/bash
```

then the cmd below

```
rclone copy /var/www/html/camera_images pictures::folder1
```

I then made the .sh file executable, and this works if I just click it in the folder and execute but if I try to call that .sh script from python with

```
os.system('sh /home/pi/py/upload.sh')
```

or

```
os.system(' rclone copy /var/www/html/camera_images pictures::folder1 ')
```

I get an error in the shell saying

> ```
> Failed to load config file "/root/.rclone.conf" using default - no such directory.
> ```

But the .conf is located in /home/pi as it should be. and if i try

```
os.system(' sh rclone copy /var/www/html/camera_images pictures::folder1 ')
```

I get

> ```
> sh: 0: Cant open rclone.
> ```

How can I can run the copy cmd or a script to do so from python?

this is how i installed rclone

3. cd
4. wget http://downloads.rclone.org/rclone-v1.34-linux-arm.zip
5. unzip rclone-v1.34-linux-arm.zip
6. cd rclone-v1.34-linux-arm
7. sudo cp rclone /usr/sbin/
8. sudo chown root:root /usr/sbin/rclone
9. sudo chmod 755 /usr/sbin/rclone
10. sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/share/man/man1
11. sudo cp rclone.1 /usr/local/share/man/man1/
12. sudo mandb
13. rclone config

Comment: Make sure your rclone program is in your system path

Comment: the rclone folder containing the rclone.exe is in my root directory /home/pi as it should be, and i can just open the shell and type the cmd rclone copy /var/www/html/camera_images pictures::folder1 and it works even if i change directory.

Comment: Ok remove the `sh` prefix and tell us

Comment: k 1 min i just loading it now

Comment: I tried both os.system('/home/pi/py/upload.sh') and os.system(' rclone copy /var/www/html/camera_images pictures::folder1 ') i both give the same message, Failed to load config file "/root/.config.conf" - using defaults: open /root/.rclone.conf: no such directory.

Comment: there is one cmd i read on the rclone site but i am unsure how to use it,

Comment: Specify the location of the rclone config file. Normally this is in your home directory as a file called .rclone.conf. If you run rclone -h and look at the help for the --config option you will see where the default location is for you. Use this flag to override the config location, eg rclone --config=".myconfig" .config.

Comment: http://rclone.org/docs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you every one :)

I have it working now with

```
os.system(' rclone copy --config /home/pi/.rclone.conf /var/www/html/camera_images pictures::folder1 ')
```

Note that if i put sh at the start i got the error sh: 0: Can't open rclone though i read yesterday about putting something like ,:0 at the end as a return value ? either way it works without the sh.

and the subprocess works too which i shall use instead.

```
subprocess.Popen('rclone copy --config /home/pi/.rclone.conf /var/www/html/camera_images pictures::folder1', shell=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use --config in your rclone command

From docs:
--config string              Config file. (default /home/ncw/.rclone.conf")

Your command should looks like:
os.system(' sh rclone copy --config /home/pi/.rclone.conf /var/www/html/camera_images pictures::folder1 ')

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `subprocess` module instead of `os.system`.

You can use [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) to create a process and give it a working directory.

```
subprocess.Popen(your_command, cwd=path_to_your_executable_dir, shell=True)
```

(Use `shell=True` to pass a simple string command among other conveniences).

> The shell argument (which defaults to False) specifies whether to use
>   the shell as the program to execute. If shell is True, it is
>   recommended to pass args as a string rather than as a sequence.
>
> On Unix with shell=True, the shell defaults to /bin/sh. If args is a
>   string, the string specifies the command to execute through the shell.
>   This means that the string must be formatted exactly as it would be
>   when typed at the shell prompt. This includes, for example, quoting or
>   backslash escaping filenames with spaces in them. If args is a
>   sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any
>   additional items will be treated as additional arguments to the shell
>   itself. That is to say, Popen does the equivalent of: ....